# Create a view in mysql with count of per hour data

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table in mysql that looks like this:

```
ID           timestamp
----------------------------
F41      2016-08-27 00:25:58
F42      2016-08-27 01:15:03
F43      2016-08-27 02:14:30
F44      2016-08-27 02:24:12
F45      2016-08-27 03:05:46
F46      2016-08-27 04:08:07
F47      2016-08-27 05:10:35
F48      2016-08-27 07:12:32
F59      2016-08-27 08:21:19
F50      2016-08-27 09:19:26
F51      2016-08-27 11:01:56
F52      2016-08-27 12:09:38
F53      2016-08-27 13:42:48
F54      2016-08-27 14:47:26
F55      2016-08-27 15:24:12
F56      2016-08-27 16:22:05
F57      2016-08-27 18:20:47
F58      2016-08-27 19:11:09
F59      2016-08-27 19:41:47
F60      2016-08-27 19:57:06
F61      2016-08-27 20:12:45
F62      2016-08-27 21:55:41
F63      2016-08-27 22:17:38
F64      2016-08-27 23:15:17
```

The ID column is not auto-increment.

I need to create a view that counts the number of records per hour that looks like this:

```
ID        time       count
------------------------------------------
1       00:00:00       1
2       01:00:00       1
3       02:00:00       1
4       03:00:00       2
5       04:00:00       1
6       05:00:00       1
7       06:00:00       1
8       07:00:00       0
9       08:00:00       1
10      09:00:00       1
11      10:00:00       1
12      11:00:00       0
13      12:00:00       1
14      13:00:00       1
15      14:00:00       1
16      15:00:00       1
17      16:00:00       1
18      17:00:00       1
19      18:00:00       0
20      19:00:00       1
21      20:00:00       3
22      21:00:00       1
23      22:00:00       1
24      23:00:00       1
```

I tried using UNION ALL and it worked but I don't know how can I join the ID column and the time column.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: What happened to the 'F's?

Comment: what's your meaning of ID ? Does it represent Hour+1 ?

Comment: The IDs on the first table is from a 22 characters barcode. It really doesn't appear like F-- or something. That Fs is the last 3 digits of the barcode and it so happens that during the testing I scanned the barcodes in ascending order.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so:

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS ID, 
       CONCAT(HOUR(`timestamp`), ':00:00') AS `time`, 
       COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM table, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
GROUP BY HOUR(`timestamp`)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should group by hour instead of using unions.

```
SELECT HOUR(timestamp) time, COUNT(*) count FROM table GROUP BY time.
```

This way there's no id, time will have numbers running from 0 to 23 and count will have number of records from that hour.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the "per hour" is before 20:00:00, so the count in 20:00:00 is 3(F58,F59,F60), and count in 19:00:00 is 1 (F57);

some extra works :P

```
select @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS ID, 
       concat((case when t.hour = 24 then 0 else t.hour end),':00:00') as time, 
       count(*) as count 
from  (select id, hour(date_format(time,'%H:%i:%s'))+1 as hour from st) t,
      (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
group by time 
order by ID;
```

SQL to create the test table and test data:

```
CREATE TABLE `st` (
  `id` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

insert into st values('F41','2016-08-27 00:25:58');
insert into st values('F42','2016-08-27 01:15:03');
insert into st values('F43','2016-08-27 02:14:30');
insert into st values('F44','2016-08-27 02:24:12');
insert into st values('F45','2016-08-27 03:05:46');
insert into st values('F46','2016-08-27 04:08:07');
insert into st values('F47','2016-08-27 05:10:35');
insert into st values('F48','2016-08-27 07:12:32');
insert into st values('F59','2016-08-27 08:21:19');
insert into st values('F50','2016-08-27 09:19:26');
insert into st values('F51','2016-08-27 11:01:56');
insert into st values('F52','2016-08-27 12:09:38');
insert into st values('F53','2016-08-27 13:42:48');
insert into st values('F54','2016-08-27 14:47:26');
insert into st values('F55','2016-08-27 15:24:12');
insert into st values('F56','2016-08-27 16:22:05');
insert into st values('F57','2016-08-27 18:20:47');
insert into st values('F58','2016-08-27 19:11:09');
insert into st values('F59','2016-08-27 19:41:47');
insert into st values('F60','2016-08-27 19:57:06');
insert into st values('F61','2016-08-27 20:12:45');
insert into st values('F62','2016-08-27 21:55:41');
insert into st values('F63','2016-08-27 22:17:38');
insert into st values('F64','2016-08-27 23:15:17');
```

learn a better way to build a auto_increament column, thx @Jacobian

Comment: I already got the table working. A view for record counts is all I need and I also need to get the zero counts in the view. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
SELECT HOUR(timestamp), COUNT(*) count FROM my_table GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp);
```

The rest of this problem is a display issue, best resolved in application level code